# Confusing paragraph in Pro Git about fake merges

Tags: git

The book [Pro Git, 2nd Edition](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) on p.289 explains a use case for fake merges:

> This can often be useful to basically trick Git into thinking that a branch is already merged when doing a merge later on.  For example, say you branched off a `release` branch and have done some work on it that you will want to merge back into your `master` branch at some point.  In the meantime some bugfix on `master` needs to be backported into your `release` branch.  You can merge the bugfix branch into the `release` branch and also `merge -s ours` the same branch into your `master` branch (even though the fix is already there) so when you later merge the `release` branch again, there are no conflicts from the bugfix.

This paragraph makes no sense to me.  (Keep in mind I’ve never used Git—I’m reading the book as a very first introduction.)

First of all, it’s talking about merging the bugfix into both the `release` branch and the `master` branch, but it had said that the bugfix was “on” `master`—which I would take to mean it was in commits done directly to `master`.  This seems to be self-contradictory as to whether there is even a separate bugfix branch or not.

Maybe “on” `master` here means that it’s already been merged into `master`, but then this seems to imply that we’re trying to fake merge the same bugfix branch into `master` that we already actually merged before.  This would seem to be reinforced by the assertion that “the fix is already there”.  But what could possibly be the point of merging the same branch, unchanged, into `master` twice?  Why wasn’t the first time enough to solve the supposed problem?

Furthermore, regardless of how the bugfix got into `master`, *why would it generate a conflict when merging from* `release`*?*  The fix should be the same lines of code on both sides of the merge, so intuitively, I would expect this merge to succeed without conflict here, without resorting to any trickery.

I’m almost wondering if the book meant to say that a bugfix in `release` was to be backported into `master`.  I’d read this to mean that the bugfix is cherry-picked into `master`.  Even in this scenario, I still don’t understand, though, why the fake merge would be needed, since again, the bugfix lines should match between both sides of the eventual merge of `release` into `master`, so shouldn’t produce a conflict.

Finally, I’m not even clear on how a fake merge would solve a merge conflict, anyway.  As best as I can tell, a fake merge would change neither the common ancestor of, nor the content on either side of, the eventual problem merge, and as such should not change its outcome at all.

Can someone explain more clearly, perhaps with a diagram, what the book is trying to get at here?  Or if I’m misunderstanding something, point out what that something is?